# Автоматы на прологе

Tags: prolog

Как найти слово длины k которое принимает недетерминированный конечный автомат в прологе(если их много, достаточно будет одного)? Автомат записываю вот так:

```
states([q0, q1, q2]).
symbols([a, b]).
transition(q0, a, q1).
transition(q0, b, q2).
transition(q1, a, q2).
transition(q1, b, q0).
transition(q2, a, q1).
transition(q2, b, q2).
startState(q0).
finalStates([q2]).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей нотации решение будет такое:

```
states([q0, q1, q2]).
symbols([a, b]).
transition(q0, a, q1).
transition(q0, b, q2).
transition(q1, a, q2).
transition(q1, b, q0).
transition(q2, a, q1).
transition(q2, b, q2).
startState(q0).
finalStates([q2]).

search(0, S, []) :-
    finalStates(FinalStates),
    member(S, FinalStates).
search(N, S1, [Head|Tail]) :-
    N > 0,
    transition(S1, Head, S2),
    M is N - 1,
    search(M, S2, Tail).

test(N, Transitions) :-
    startState(S),
    search(N, S, Transitions).
```

> ```
> $ swipl -s automata.pl
> Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.2.3)
> Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
> SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
> and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
> Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.
>
> For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).
>
> ?- test(4, X).
> X = [a, a, a, a] ;
> X = [a, a, b, b] ;
> X = [a, b, a, a] ;
> X = [a, b, b, b] ;
> X = [b, a, a, b] ;
> X = [b, a, b, b] ;
> X = [b, b, a, a] ;
> X = [b, b, b, b] ;
> false.
> ```

Comment: спасибо большое)